# Python - Why str() and type() return different data types on the same SQLAlchemy base class?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying some **SQLAlchemy** sample code. And I am curious why the following `str()` and `type()` calls return different class types on the same object.

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
>>> b = declarative_base()
>>> str(b)
"<class 'sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api.Base'>"
>>> type(b)
<class 'sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api.DeclarativeMeta'>
```

I have checked the source code, the only class definition I can find is `DeclarativeMeta`.

Can somebody please explain why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

`str` returns a string representation of an object.  `type` returns the *type* of the object, which is different from the object itself.  There is no reason to suppose that these will be the same, and they typically are not:

```
>>> str({})
'{}'
>>> type({})
<type 'dict'>
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
>>> str(Foo)
"<class '__main__.Foo'>"
>>> type(Foo)
<type 'type'>
```

Your case is similar to the second example above (with class `Foo`).  Calling `declarative_base` returns a class.  That class has metaclass DeclarativeMeta.  Calling `str` on the class gives the name of the class itself, which by default is "Base".  Calling `type` on it returns its type.  The type of a class is its metaclass, so this returns `DeclarativeBase`.